# Native ABI mismatch from package

Tags: android, virtualbox, android-x86

So, I'm trying to use Android x86 and virtual box to debug my apps.

I've successfully deployed a hello world apk to the Android x86 running in virtualbox.
(connecting via adb vboxIP:5555

So next I tried to debug my game:

When I do so I get the following messages in logcat

```
Package has mismatched uid:10044 on disc, 10048 in settings
Native ABI mismatch from package file.
```

My game includes a amreabi package (box2d)

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by the Android NDK being built into my application and not in an x86 compatible way. NDK references a specific version of the armeabi stuff. My answer was as simple as removing NDK/JNI because it wasn't being used in the current version. Apparently, it is possible to build with the NDK for the x86 platform: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html (see the revision 6b comment list).